# How to run SWTBOT in eclipse juno

Tags: java, swtbot

I am not finding any clear documents to start the Swtbot. I am trying couple of days to start it.
Can any one please help me configuring and executing the swtbot?

Comment: What do you have completed so far?

Answer (score 1):

If you are just starting with SWTBot, it's good to start with running it on Eclipse IDE(assuming you're using Eclipse).

Install SWTBot in Eclipse from update site http://download.eclipse.org/technology/swtbot/releases/latest/.

Now go to Run Configurations and find a section named SWTBot Test on left side.

Right click and create a new SWTBot launch file.

In the Main tab you can configure which class or suite or test method to execute.

You can also configure which product you want to run your tests on.
It'd be more helpful to answer if you provided with how far you have gone.

Answer (score 0):

If you're in IDE (with SWTBot installed in it), just right-click on your Test Case and select "Run As > SWTBot Test Case". This will create a good enough launch configuration (that you can refine later if necessary).

If you're trying to run tests independently of the IDE, please read https://wiki.eclipse.org/SWTBot/Automate_test_execution